# C#/VB.Net Web Browser Control Replacement

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I've been working on a project that requires that I can go around webpages with different proxies, user-agents, and clear cookies. Now after looking all around the net, it looks like there are some solutions for each of these, but I can never get them working. I was wondering if there was a wrapper for this control that fixed all of these problems or even just a different control I could include. Thanks.

Edit: I tried using HTTPWebRequest, it has everything I need -Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the GeckoFX Engine is Right for you....

[Click ME](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/wiki/GettingStarted)